# I need to make a little space in the below text box i tried many ways but i can't

Tags: php, html

I'm new to coding and required a little help here i have created a page of my website "complaint form" the problem is i can't be able to make a little space in the textbox. Here to know if someone tell me where is the problem also i think there are many unnecessary& could you please let me know or fine the code. Thanks
PS: if i run this code on online compiler the spaces are fine enough.
The current pic of below code [Current textbox space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3hZq.png)

```html
<table width="450px">
<table class="formcontrols">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20" size="30" required>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="20" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="CNIC_No">CNIC No/NICOP * </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="CNIC_No" placeholder="Registered CNIC/NICOP"maxlength="16" size="30"required>
 </td>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Registered Email"maxlength="29" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Mobile No">Mobile No *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" "name="Mobile no" placeholder="Registered Mobile" maxlength="15" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Cleint Code">Cleint Code *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" "name="Cleint Code" placeholder="Cleint Code" maxlength="05" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Address">Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="Address" maxlength="60" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="06"required></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
 <font color="red">Note: Complaint will be only entertain if all details are match with account</font> </br>
 <br>
```

Comment: It's better to use the css style `padding-left` for your textbox.

Comment: your solution helps me to sort out my problem i just did "style="padding-bottom:05px;">

Comment: Now i'm stuck how do i receive the email on submit button..

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure why are you doing your form with table. Also there was a lot of syntax errors. I tried to fix it. In my point of view your form should look like this:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.form-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
 }

.form-content .content {  
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content label {
  width: 20%;
}
.content input, textarea {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .form-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .form-content .content {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }  
  .content label {
  width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="" class="form-content">
      <div class="content">
        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20" required>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="20">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="CNIC_No">CNIC No/NICOP * </label>
        <input type="text" id="CNIC_No" placeholder="Registered CNIC/NICOP" maxlength="16" required>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Registered Email" maxlength="29" required>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="mobile_No">Mobile No *</label>
        <input type="text" id="mobile_no" placeholder="Registered Mobile" maxlength="15" required>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="cleint_code">Cleint Code *</label>
        <input  type="text" id="cleint_code" placeholder="Cleint Code" maxlength="05" required>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input  type="text" id="address" maxlength="60" >
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
        <textarea id="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="06" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button"/>
      </div>
   </form>
   <font color="red">Note: Complaint will be only entertain if all details are match with account</font>
</div>
```

Hope i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what space do you need, but you can always control padding, margin, height, width and line-height with CSS

if you can see at the top of the table.. i added 
to declare the style of input boxes below.

```html
<style>
input, textarea {border: 1px solid #000000; border-radius: 3px; width: 390px; padding: 10px; outline: none}
.submit-button {background: #597ade; color: #FFF;}
</style>
<table width="450px">
<table class="formcontrols">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20" size="30" required>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="20" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="CNIC_No">CNIC No/NICOP * </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="CNIC_No" placeholder="Registered CNIC/NICOP"maxlength="16" size="30"required>
 </td>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Registered Email"maxlength="29" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Mobile No">Mobile No *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" "name="Mobile no" placeholder="Registered Mobile" maxlength="15" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Cleint Code">Cleint Code *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" "name="Cleint Code" placeholder="Cleint Code" maxlength="05" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Address">Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="Address" maxlength="60" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="60" rows="06"required></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
 <font color="red">Note: Complaint will be only entertain if all details are match with account</font> </br>
 <br>
```

in the **style** you can add
padding: 5px; - means 5(any number depending if your eyes likes it) pixel gives you more space inside the textbox.

line-height: mostly 6+ pixel higher than your font-size so you have more distances in every lines in your textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin in your style e.g margin-left: 40px and the box will be adjusted to the left (See your edited code). I left the first box to give the difference. If you want from spaces from the top you can add margin-top too.

```html
<table width="450px">
<table class="formcontrols">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text"  name="first_name" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20" size="30" required>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" maxlength="20" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="CNIC_No">CNIC No/NICOP * </label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;" name="CNIC_No" placeholder="Registered CNIC/NICOP"maxlength="16" size="30"required>
 </td>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;" name="email" placeholder="Registered Email"maxlength="29" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Mobile No">Mobile No *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;" name="Mobile no placeholder" placeholder= "Registered Mobile" maxlength="15" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Cleint Code">Cleint Code *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;"  name="Cleint Code" placeholder="Cleint Code" maxlength="05" size="30"required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Address">Address</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" style="margin-left: 30px;" name="Address" maxlength="60" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="60" style="margin-left: 30px;" rows="06"required></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button"/>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
 <font color="red">Note: Complaint will be only entertain if all details are match with account</font> </br>
 <br>
```